# Retain transparency of an image created on bitmap in VB.NET application

Tags: vb.net, image, bitmap, visual-studio-2005, windows

I have to draw an image on surface on windows application built in Visual Studio 2005.

The image is of type .png and it contains a transparent background.

When I create a bitmap with the image and draw on the window (in onPaint Event), the image loses its transparency background and transperancy part of image turns into white colour. How can I retain the transparency?

Comment: It's most likely the window's background being mixed with the transparent pixels. The image itself would in that case be fine. Please share your code and perhaps a screenshot showing the problem, it makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Call this on the bitmap object, replacing "Color tranparentColor" with the color you want to be transparent:

```
myBitmap->MakeTransparent(Color transparentColor);
```

If you want the upper left pixel of the bmp to be the transparent color, you would do this:

```
  // Get the color of a background pixel.
  Color backColor = myBitmap->GetPixel( 1, 1 );

  // Make backColor transparent for myBitmap.
  myBitmap->MakeTransparent( backColor );
```